# how to plot binary data over time (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a dataframe that looks like the below and am attempting to plot user behavior over time. For example, Benny wrote more letters over all but also wrote more letters at the beginning of this trial. His data might look like "AB1C2...". Bo wrote less letters overall but also wrote more letters of the beginning of the trial. Her data might book like "AB1C234..."

Toy example:

```
Name     Seconds   Type     Value

Benny    1         letter    TRUE 
Benny    2         letter    TRUE 
Benny    3         letter    FALSE 
Benny    4         letter    TRUE 
Benny    5         letter    FALSE 
Bo       1         letter    TRUE 
Bo       2         letter    TRUE 
Bo       3         letter    FALSE
Bo       4         letter    TRUE
Bo       5         letter    FALSE 
Bo       6         letter    FALSE 
Bo       6         letter    FALSE 
Bo       7         letter    FALSE 
...      ...       ...       ...
```

I've attempted to plot this with:

```
counts <- data %>% 
  group_by(Name, Seconds, Type, Value) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Name, Seconds, Type, Value) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(count))

plot <- ggplot(counts, aes(x=seconds, y=sum, color=Type)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(.~Name)
```

But as you'll be able to see, this plot is not that informative since it's not accumulative. Does anyone have advice on a better way to plot this? Specifically, I'm imagining that each person would have two lines (one showing an increase or decrease in TRUE values over time, and a second line showing an increase of decrease of FALSE values over time), but have not been able to figure this out.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

data <- tibble(
  Name = c(rep("Benny", 5), rep("B0", 8)),
  Type = rep("Letter", 13),
  Seconds = c(1:5, 1:6, 6, 7),
  Value = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE )
)

counts <- data %>% 
  group_by(Name, Seconds, Type, Value) %>% 
  mutate(count = ifelse(Value == TRUE, 1, -1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Name, Value) %>%
  mutate(sum = cumsum(count))

ggplot(counts, aes(x = Seconds, y = sum, colour = Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(Value~Name)
```

[image]